# Django default image does not seem to load

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Looked at a bunch of answers and tried to fix them, but my default image for profile.html does not seem to load. What I'm I doing wrong and how can I solve, in case it happens again? Thanks.

This is my default [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYiJ6.jpg).

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

profile.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
    <div class="media">
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h2 class="account-heading">{{user.username}}</h2>
        <p class="text-secondary">{{user.email}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- FORM HERE -->
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Relevant settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from django.contrib import messages

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created, you are now able to log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html')
```

Comment: Do you have placed the default image in `media/default.jpg`
Maybe you have uploaded the default.jpg in `media/profile_pics/default.jpg`

Comment: Please show your views.py which renders profile.html

Comment: @dipesh it's in media/default.jpg.

Comment: @alvo just did it.

Comment: Does `<h2 class="account-heading">{{user.username}}</h2>`display the username properly?

Comment: @alvo yes. Do you think it might be a bug with Django itself?

Comment: No. In your `def profile(request)` it doesn't look like you're passing in any context, so I can't understand how ``{{ user.username }}` display correctly?

Answer (score 0):

try removing the user with default image. now after you've placed the above codes, try creating a new user not providing any image. It should now use the default.jpeg you already placed in the media folder.